# Chamberlin Keypad work with a Linear motor

Tags: garage-door-opener

I replaced an old Chamberlin garage door open with a Linear LDO50 motor.  I have a Chamberlin garage door opener keypad (model unknown) mounted on the outside of the garage. I’m trying to program the keypad with a new PIN.  Doesn’t seem to be working. I pressed the learn button on the Linear motor, keyed a PIN into to the keypad and held the enter key down.  The Linear motor times out in 15 seconds.  The instructions on the Chamberlain keypad says it may take up to 30 secs to set the PIN.

Is the Chamberlin keypad compatible with Linear motor?

Comment: Does Chamberlin only make one keypad? Is there only one kind of linear motor? Probably not. Perhaps you should add a little more detail to your question.

Comment: Chamberlain outdoor keypads are typically wireless.  With a chamberlain unit they would ask you which keypad you have and they would ask which color your programming button is, with those 2 details they can tell you if the devices are compatible.  There are several garage door frequencies and several code rolling technologies—they are not all magically compatible with each other.

Comment: BTW Chamberlain/LiftMaster has world class customer support.  They don’t care how old the installed unit is, they will talk you thru any needed programming/reprogramming or adjustments over the phone.  I doubt they’ll be able to support this tho since they didn’t make the motor.

Comment: When you say "motor " do you mean "garage door opener"?

Comment: I found out the Chamberlin keypad is not compatible with the Linear opener.   I have placed an order for a Linear keypad.